# CORS no funciona con el metodo POST

Tags: php, angular, post, cors

estoy trabajando en una app Angular que consume una API en php alojada en otro dominio. Todas mis peticiones GET funcionan perfectamente, pero las peticiones POST fallan devolviendo el siguiente error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

En el .htacces de mi API tengo agregados los encabezados CORS y en el service Angular las cabeceras que he leido que son necesarias, sin embargo, con o sin ellas recibo siempre la misma respuesta.

Dejo el codigo.
Si alguien sabe como puedo slucionarlo seria genial. Gracias!

**.htccess completo:**

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'https://*******'
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteRule \.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ routerAPI.php?resource=$1 [QSA,L,END]
</IfModule>
```

**Ruta en routerAPI.php:**

```
$router->addRoute('log', 'POST', 'UserController', 'verify');
```

Lo anterior envia al controlador que se encarga de hacer todo el trabajo.

**Solicitud en el service de Angular:**

```
public login(user: UserLogin): Observable<UserStatus>  {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    headers.set('Access-Control-Request-Method', 'POST' );
    return this.http.post<UserStatus>(URL_LOG,user, {headers: headers})
    .pipe(
      map((res:UserStatus)=> {
        return res;
        
      })
    )
  }
```

Todo esto ya fue probado loalmente utilizando un proxy.conf.json y andaba a la perfeccion, pero esa solucion es para dev y no funciona en prod, supongo que la falla esta en la manera en que agrego los encabezados en el servidor o en lgun encabezado que falta en los request.

Siempre lo estuve probando en chrome, y no tenia ningun otro detalle del error, lo probe en firefox y el error dice lo siguiente:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://******. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
Por lo visto, estoy haciendo algo mal en mi request, pero no se que puede ser.

Comment: El problema mayormente es del servidor, podrías poner el código del servidor?

Comment: El servidor comienza en el .htacces que contiene los encabezados de cors y el codigo que sigue:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteRule \.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ routerAPI.php?resource=$1 [QSA,L,END]
</IfModule>
Dirige a mi routerAPI que genera la siguiente ruta y sigue en el controlador
$router->addRoute('log', 'POST', 'UserController', 'verify');
Todo esto ya fue probado localmente y funcionaba a la perfeccion, solo que no funciona en prod.

Comment: Podrias poner eso en tu pregunta, ya que no se aprecia muy bien en un comentario y es difícil de leer

Comment: Ahi lo agregue, muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RESUELTO

Dejo la solucion por si le sirve a alguien mas.

El problema era que estaba enviando los json en formato json directamente. Habia intentado hacer el post enviando directamente user y utilizando JSON.parse(JSON.stringigy(user)) y no funcionaba. La manera correcta era JSoN.stringify(user). Con esto se soluciono el problema.

Comment: Que bueno que hayas resuelto tu problema

Comment: En 24 horas, regresa a esta pregunta y márcala como resuelta mediante un click en el check verde del costado. Que sigan los éxitos :D